# How to convert VMware virtual SCSI disk to new virtual NVMe disk?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

VMware Workstation Pro 14 now supports virtual NVMe drives.

What is the easiest way to convert existing virtual SCSI disk to the new virtual NVMe disk?

Answer (score 14):

The first step is to get Windows to load the new drivers. This can be done by adding a second drive to the computer:

1. Power off the virtual machine.
2. Add a new NVMe disk to the virtual machine.
3. Power on the virtual machine.
4. Ensure VMWare Tools has been upgraded to the latest version.

The second step is to manually modify the .vmx file:

1. Power off the virtual machine.
2. Close out of the virtual machine in VMWare Workstation.
3. Make a backup copy of the .vmx file
4. Open the .vmx file in a text editor (Such as Notepad++)
5. Delete any lines starting with **scsi0**
6. Scroll to the bottom. You will see the new NVMe entries that were created for the new drive. It will start with **nvme0**
7. Search for nvme0:0.fileName = "SOMEFILE.vmdk"
8. Change the file name to be the file containing your virtual machine's C: drive.
9. Save the .vmx file.
10. Open the virtual machine in VMWare Workstation and power it on.

Taken from http://techninotes.blogspot.com/2017/10/migrating-existing-virtual-machines-to.html.

Comment: For anyone curious: the reverse also works (add a scsi drive, start up, power off, remove all nvme0 lines and change the scsi0.fileName to the one used for nvme previously)